# What is the statistical power required for COVID-19 vaccine trials?

Tags: vaccination, coronavirus, statistics

Clinical research selects the number of subjects under treatment based on desired **statistical power** (i.e. the probability of rejecting the null hypothesis when the null is in effect false, given a certain confidence level). Usual guidelines are for power to be no less than 80% (e.g. [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3148614/)). I wonder whether the Covid vaccines under study have a **higher or lower** required power than usual. I have found, unsurprisingly, no information available on the actual number of subjects, let alone the power assumed, by Covid trials currently undertaken.

**Is anyone aware of the assumptions in terms of power used for some Covid vaccine trials?**